# State the approximate distribution of Y giving its Parameters and work out $ P(Y <22)$

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, sampling

This is the question
[[image: enter image description here1]
I tried solving it and the X-N (21,4.2^2/100) is correct but the probability is wrong its spouse to be 0.954. I have no teacher to ask as I am self-studying any help would be much appreciated. this is my work thank you!
[image]

This is similar example:
[image]

Comment: According to the central limit theorem you have $\bar Y \stackrel{\approx}{\sim} N\left(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right) = N\left(21, \frac{4.2^2}{\color{blue}{50}}\right)$. So, your start already with a wrong standard deviation for $\bar Y$.

Comment: In your second example a so called correction for continuity is added which gives rise to the $\frac 1{100}$. $\bar X$ can assume values starting from $0$ only in steps of $\frac 1{50}$. So, one would have $P(\bar X \leq 16) = P(\bar X < 16+\frac 1{50})$. Using the normal approximation you would get two different results. Hence, when using the normal approximation a correction of half a step $\frac 12\cdot \frac 1{50}$ is introduced to account for that discrepancy. If the number of observations is large, one may skip this correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you correct your standard deviation for $\bar Y$, you will get with $n=50$ observations

$$Z = \frac{\bar Y - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}}\stackrel{\approx}{\sim}N(0,1)$$

and
$$P\left(\bar Y < 22\right)= P\left(Z < \frac{22-21}{\frac{4.2}{\sqrt{50}}}\right)=P\left(Z<\frac{\sqrt{50}}{4.2}\right)\approx 0.954$$

Comment: Thank you very much but one this I don't get is some times they say 1/100 added to the value and some ties I am not spouse to do so . do you know why maybe.

Comment: @maryjames I would need more context to answer this, since I do not know where the $\frac 1{100}$ comes from. But when it comes to the mean, then with increasing number of observations the central limit theorem comes into play. And there the formula for the standard deviation is clearly $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: I will add an example to the question could you look at it.

Comment: could you look at it ?